# Javascript split function to split into array at new line or white space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split some text either by whitespace and/or new line, and also remove the white space before and after the whole text, just in case.  I'm not sure how to perform this as I cannot get my head around regex (I've tried other people's regex but it breaks my output) and I want to perform this using best practice rather than writing some lengthy buggy workaround

My code can be located here:  https://github.com/Dave-Melia/Text-Separator

Many thanks

D

Comment: Always put all relevant code **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: I can be helped without the code as I only need the function and regex.  The code is just to give an idea what I'm doing.

Comment: The code is either relevant or it isn't. If it's relevant, it goes in the question. If it isn't, you don't link to it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To split on any whitespace (including newlines), you'd use `/\s/` with `split`:

```
var theArray = theString.split(/\s+/);
```

`\s` means "spaces" (e.g., whitespace — including newlines), and `+` means "one *or more*".

To trim whitespace from the beginning and end of the string first, on any modern browser you can use `String#trim`:

```
var theArray = theString.trim().split(/\s+/);
```

If you have to support older browsers, you can use `replace`:

```
var theArray = theString.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/);
```

That regex used with `replace` can use a bit of explanation: http://regex101.com/r/sS0zV3/1

- `^\s+` means "any whitespace at the beginning of the string
- `|` means "or" (as in , "this *or* that") (it's called an "alternation")
- `\s+$` means "any whitepsace at the end of the string

Then we replace all occurrences (`g`) with `''` (a blank string).

Comment: you don't need the `g` operator in `/^\s+|\s+$/`, I'd say.

Comment: @KooiInc: You do if you want to remove both leading and trailing whitespace. E.g., `"  foo  ".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` is `"foo"`, but `"  foo  ".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '')` is `"foo  "`

Comment: @ all: I forgot to type a `+` in the `split` string. If you don't see it above, hit refresh.

Comment: Thank you both for your support -- this works like a charm

Answer (score 4):

You can split on a regular expression, in that `\s` is for all whitespace including newlines, so:

```
'  bla\nblabla blablabla\n blablablabla'
  .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')
  .split(/\s+/);
//=> ["bla", "blabla", "blablabla", "blablablabla"]
```

Comment: You've done it again -- many thanks for your support

Comment: What about simply using `.replace(/\s+/g,'')`?

Comment: @Con Antonakos: in that case there wouLd be nothing to split. Try it out and see for yourself

Answer (score 2):

The split function takes a regexp

```
var a = "foo bar\nfoo".split(/\s/)    
// this returns ["foo", "bar", "foo"]
```

And if you have multiple whitespaces (note the plus sign)

```
var a = "foo    bar  \n  foo".split(/\s+/)    
// this returns ["foo", "bar", "foo"]
```

And to get rid of whitespases before and after you can use trim() first

```
var a = "   foo    bar  \n  foo   ".trim().split(/\s+/)    
// this returns ["foo", "bar", "foo"]
```

Answer (score 2):

To split by spaces you can use `\s` in regular expressions
For line breaks you can use `\n` (and `\r`)

I created an example that breaks down and removes the array items that are empty.

Note: In the following example I added and spaces breaks the null character.

```js
function splitText(data) {
    return String(data).split(/[\0\s]+/g).filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(splitText(" dat a    a "));
```

IE8:

```js
function splitText(data) {
    var arr = String(data).split(/[\0\s]+/g), i, j, v = [];

    j = arr.length;

    for (i = 0; i < j; i += 1) {
        if (arr[i] !== "") {
            v.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    arr = null;
    return v;
}

alert(splitText(" dat a  a "));
```