# How to store Javascript data in CSV file

Tags: javascript, php, csv, web-scraping

I am fetching data using PhantomJs Library

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('https://www.apwagner.com/appliance-part/wpl/wp661600', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
      return document.getElementById('ModelList').textContent;  
      //return document.getElementById('ModelList').innerHTML; 
    });
    console.log(ua);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Output

```
             1DNET3205TQ0
             7MMMS0100VW0
             7MMMS0100VW1
             7MMMS0120VM0
             7MMMS0140VW0
             7MMMS0160VW0
```

If I am trying to get output using innerHTML then output like

```
    <ul class="modelnos">
                        <li><a class="cursor" href="/appliance/1dnet3205tq0" onclick="return ProductService.SaveLogModelView('1DNET3205TQ0', 'MAC')"> 1DNET3205TQ0</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cursor" href="/appliance/7mmms0100vw0" onclick="return ProductService.SaveLogModelView('7MMMS0100VW0', 'MAC')"> 7MMMS0100VW0</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cursor" href="/appliance/7mmms0100vw1" onclick="return ProductService.SaveLogModelView('7MMMS0100VW1', 'MAC')"> 7MMMS0100VW1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cursor" href="/appliance/7mmms0120vm0" onclick="return ProductService.SaveLogModelView('7MMMS0120VM0', 'MAC')"> 7MMMS0120VM0</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cursor" href="/appliance/7mmms0140vw0" onclick="return ProductService.SaveLogModelView('7MMMS0140VW0', 'MAC')"> 7MMMS0140VW0</a></li>
</ul>
```

But as the output in variable, I want this output in array format.

like `var models = ["1DNET3205TQ0", "7MMMS0100VW0", "7MMMS0100VW1"];`

and put this array in csv file.

How can I get this data in array and put in csv.

**Updates :**

Actually I want to create table html from each values in that array.

Like 3 columns in tables.

```
<table>
<tr><td> 1DNET3205TQ0 </td>
<td> 7MMMS0100VW0 </td>
<td> 7MMMS0100VW1 </td>
</tr>
<tr><td> 7MMMS0120VM0 </td>
<td> 7MMMS0140VW0 </td>
<td> 7MMMS0160VW0 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write data to file using only JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript)

Comment: For the first part, instead of `console.log(ua)` you can push values in an array.

Comment: Try `split()` function to create array. `ua.split('\n')` or `ua.split(' ')` depending on the delimiter in the string. It will return an array

Comment: how can I push this data into array. this data prints all at once

Comment: @abhishekkannojia anu Please checj updates in question

Answer (score 0):

A combination of using the `split()` function and the `join()` function can achieve the proper result..  (see `comments` inside of code for detailed explanations)

the comments are displayed in `grey` and have a `/*`  and `*/` around them

```js
/* create a new array for  ua values */

var my_array = [];

var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('https://www.apwagner.com/appliance-part/wpl/wp661600', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
      return document.getElementById('ModelList').textContent;
      //return document.getElementById('ModelList').innerHTML; 
    });
    console.log(ua);

    /*  split    ua   to an array */
    my_array = ua.split(/\s+/);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});

/* now at the end to make into a 'csv' use join() */
/*  the ',' parameter specifies what character to put      in between the values */

var csv_array = my_array.join(",");
console.log(csv_array);
```

---

Steps to repdocuce:

1. create a variable to store the values in with   `var my_array = [];`
2. In your function, use `my_array.split(/\s+/);` will split the result into an array by using a `regular expression` to match `whitespace`
3. Once finished with the loop, use  `my_array.join(",");`  to combine all values into a single string  with a "," in between each value

**EDIT**

To make the results into a table,  instead of using `my_array.join()`, use a `for` loop, and each time the loop passes, you have to `grab` the array value with `my_array[i]`  where `i` represents the index of the array,  and then use `document.createElement()`  to create the various `table`, `tr`, and `td` elements, and finally use  `appendChild()`  to insert the elements into the proper parent elements to create your table

In the example i added a destination div where the table will be added to as well

```js
/* original array from other snippet */
var my_array = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"];

/* new table element */
var new_table = document.createElement("table");

/*  for loop which sets i to a value for each value listed in my_array */
for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {

  /* create a row */
  var new_row = document.createElement("tr");

  /* create a cell for that row */
  var new_cell = document.createElement("td");

  /* set the text in the created cell */
  new_cell.innerText = my_array[i];

  /* add the cell to the row */
  new_row.appendChild(new_cell);

  /* add the row to the table */
  new_table.appendChild(new_row);

}
/* destination div */
var destination = document.getElementById("table_destination");

/* add the table to the destination div */
destination.appendChild(new_table);
```

```css
#table_destination > table,
td {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="table_destination"></div>
```

Comment: `push()` is used to put a single value in array, it wont create an array of values. You need `split()` instead

Comment: I just updated my answer to take into account what @anu said

Comment: Also, it doesnt necesaarily be a whitespace, it could be a newline as separator. So you need to try `split('\n')` if whitespace doesnt work.

Comment: @anu actually `split(/\s+/)`  matches newlines **and** whitespace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218677/javascript-split-function-to-split-into-array-at-new-line-or-white-space

Comment: Great then my bad

Comment: @anu Its an easy mistake to make -- regex (regular expressions) are seldom well-documented/consistent across platforms  so in some languages, you are most likely correct that newlines would also have to be matched -- javascript  fortunately treats any non-character space as whitespace

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('https://www.apwagner.com/appliance-part/wpl/wp661600', function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementById('ModelList').textContent;
        });
        console.log(ua);
        array = ua.split(/\s+/);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});

var fs = require('fs');
//for users running with node
/*fs.writeFile("/home/data.csv", array.join(','), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});*/
//for users running with phantomjs
fs.write('/home/data.csv', array.join(','), 'w');
```

Comment: file is not created at location. getting error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'fs.writeFile')`

Comment: you are executing this with `node` or `phantomjs`. If `phantomjs` then please use `fs.write(path, content, 'w')` in place of `fs.writeFile`

Comment: can you please simple create an array of that variable `ua` so I can create table from that array.

Comment: u want to store in csv file or you want to create a html table? the variable `array` is containing all values in an array you can iterate on that

Comment: above solution not working like some encoding error while opening csv file.  I want a html table format of that which can be put in csv file